# Is it common for method beginning with "get" to actually set properties?

Tags: java, android, getter

I was surprised to learn that the Android API allows us to resizes imageView objects by calling the getLayoutParams() method. For example:

```
myTimerBar.getLayoutParams().width = timeRemaining;
```

There is no corresponding setLayoutParams() method.

Is it common for methods that have the word "get" to also allow programmers to "set" properties? I realize that this method is not technically a "getter" method, but it does start with the word "get."

Comment: `setLayoutParams()` most certainly exists:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`getLayoutParams()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutParams%28%29) returns [`ViewGroup.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) which it has an instance variable [`width`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#width) that is declared as public, and in Java you can access a public instance variable and set a new value to it without a setter method.

For example:

```
public class Point
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
```

```
Point p = new Point();
p.x = 10;
p.y = p.x + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

there is setLayoutParams() in Android SDK since API Level 1
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it common for methods that have the word "get" to also allow
>   programmers to "set" properties? I realize that this method is not
>   technically a "getter" method, but it does start with the word "get.

It does return the `LayoutParams` object associated with the `View`. This object does not have a mutable state. But `View` class does have [`setLayoutParams()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29), so does any sub-class of `View`. You will have to create a new `LayoutParams` to set.